# Reverse for 'facebook_login' in django-allauth

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm using django-allauth with app engine and when I add login_required decorator to my view I get the following error: Reverse for 'facebook_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
The full traceback is here: http://slexy.org/view/s20Zs7JvFl

My settings:

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (...,

"allauth.account.context_processors.account",

"allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",

)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

"allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (

...,

'allauth',

'allauth.account',

'allauth.socialaccount',

'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

)

I probably miss something stupid. What should I do in order to move a step forward?
Thanks, Alex

Comment: did you update your urls.py ?

Comment: I added url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))

Comment: Do I need to add something else?

Comment: did you add key/secret to db?

Comment: I added AWS_KEY and SECRET_KEY to setting.py and that's all.

Comment: Could you try: "python manage.py shell; from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.urls import *" -- does this import succeed, or do you get an ImportError?

Comment: How about this then?: "python manage.py shell; from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse; reverse('/accounts/facebook/login/')" -- does it return '/accounts/facebook/login/' ?

Comment: No. I get the same error: Reverse for '/accounts/facebook/login/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You need to ship the requests library with your app; I just copied it over from /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib to /path/to/my/app.

Longer explanation: The allauth Facebook provider requires the "requests" library to work properly. Interestingly, the Google App Engine does ship it (see path above), but as of now it is not in the "public interface" of libraries that can be referenced (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). I assume the App Engine ships the library because it is needed by one of the public libraries in the list above. It would be cool if the App Engine added it to the list of public libraries, so users could just refefence it in the app.yaml file, but the workaround described here works for me.